# Working on a react redux project, when I make a axios.post action the payload is empty with store.getState() but it works without

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is the userMiddleware...

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import {
  SUBMIT_NEW_USER,
  SUBMIT_LOGIN,
  saveAuthData,
} from 'src/actions/form';

const userMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SUBMIT_NEW_USER:

      axios.post(
        'xxxxxx/api/users',
        {
          firstname: store.getState().userNameSubscribe,
          lastname: store.getState().userLastNameSubscribe,
          phoneNumber: store.getState().userPhoneSubscribe,
          email: store.getState().userMailSubscribe,
          personalAddress: store.getState().userAdressSubscribe,
          password: store.getState().userPasswordSubscribe,
        },
      )
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })

        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

      break;

    case SUBMIT_LOGIN:

      axios.post(
        'xxxxxxx/api/login_check',
        {
          username: store.getState().logInEmail,
          password: store.getState().logInPassword,
        },
      )
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          store.dispatch(saveAuthData(response.data.token));

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      break;

  }

  next(action);
};

export default userMiddleware;
```

here is the userReducer:

```
import { HANDLE_CHANGE, SAVE_AUTH_DATA } from '../actions/form';

const initialState = {
  userNameSubscribe: '',
  userLastNameSubscribe: '',
  userPhoneSubscribe: '',
  userMailSubscribe: '',
  userAdressSubscribe: '',
  userPasswordSubscribe: '',


  logInEmail: '',
  logInPassword: '',
  token: '',
  loged: false,

};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_FORM:
      return {
        ...state,
        openLogin: !state.openLogin,
      };
    case HANDLE_CHANGE:

      return {
        ...state,
        [action.name]: action.value,
      };
    case SAVE_AUTH_DATA:

      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.token,
        loged: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default userReducer;
```

the rootreducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import spaceReducer from './spaceReducer';
import userReducer from './userReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  space: spaceReducer,
  user: userReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and finally the store:

```
  import { legacy_createStore as createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import reducer from 'src/reducers';

import userMiddleware from '../middleware/userMiddleware';
import spaceMiddleware from '../middleware/spaceMiddleware';

const middlewares = applyMiddleware(
  userMiddleware,
  spaceMiddleware,

);

const enhancer = composeWithDevTools(middlewares);

const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer);


export default store;
```

In the userMiddleware if I put username: name@email.com and password: therealpassword
instead of using store.getState().logInEmail and store.getState().logInPassword : name@email.com and therealpassword are in the payload which is not the case when I use the getState()....

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

with two reducers I had to precise it in the userMiddleware, so store.getState().user instead of just store.getState() did the job.